# How to upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 on Windows dual boot?

Tags: boot, upgrade, 20.04

Currently, I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed along with Windows 10. I have downloaded 20.04 ISO. I'm thinking about just burning the ISO to a USB drive then install 20.04 from the USB. Will this approach keep my dual boot intact? Thanks.

Comment: The drive size I assigned to Ubuntu is too small, only 20GB. I think the direct upgrade requires more space.

Comment: You haven't indicated if you're talking a desktop or server, but the minimum recommended space was 25GB for a desktop install; part of which is the space required to *release-upgrade*  Lots of *unofficial* blogs say you can use less space because they *nuke & install* (ie. clean install)  You could expand your partition, or *upgrade via re-install* by using existing partition(s) & ensuring you don't format your system (ie. system directories are erased; but user files are not touched, additional packages are attempted to be re-added if available on new release), but minimums exist for a reason

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I didn't know the min hard drive size is 25GB. I want to do clean reinstall 20.04. If I boot from the USB/ISO 20.04, can I delete the existing ubuntu and expand the size to 25GB then install 20.04? I don't need to keep anything in current ubuntu drive. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, however you'll have to have a 25GB space on the drive; either 5GB next to your 20GB partition, or another place on the drive with a 25GB free spot. You can move partitions around (shrink & re-size) but that involves risk to anything on any partition changed (so backup first!!) in case anything goes wrong.  The amount of space needed will depend on what you do, for my use I need 27GB for normal operation; 32GB to *release-upgrade* but I know many feel 15GB is fine for normal use, etc... The more software you add, the more space you require.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)